# Get corrosponding record Of Row in Another Column of SQL Table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am having SQL table where the records of the employee on daily basis are stored/saved I would like to get that result in tabular format

Consider a Table As Shown Below

```
 NAME     | DATEANDTIME         | ACTION 
----------|---------------------|-----------
JOHN      | 2019-07-07 10:00:00 |   INTIME
JOHN      | 2019-07-07 18:00:00 |   OUTTIME
WILLIAM   | 2019-07-07 10:02:00 |   INTIME
CATHERIN  | 2019-07-07 10:10:00 |   INTIME
JOHN      | 2019-07-07 13:00:00 |   LUNCH
CATHERIN  | 2019-07-07 18:30:00 |   OUTTIME
CATHERIN  | 2019-07-07 14:30:00 |   LUNCH
WILLIAM   | 2019-07-07 19:14:00 |   INTIME
```

I want above table to be displayed in the vertical format as it should be group as per the name

I had tried using the pivot query but it is not giving me expected output

```
 select
    Dateandtime,
    [name],
    [action]
from
    (
        select Dateandtime,
        [name],
        [action]
    from
        table1) a pivot(max(action) for tagindex in (Dateandtime,
    [name],
    [action]))pvt


   INTIME            |      OUTTIME          | LUNCH               |  NAME
---------------------|-----------------------|---------------------|--------
#2019-07-07 10:00:00 | 2019-07-07 18:00:00   |        -------      | WILLIAM                                                    
#2019-07-07 10:10:00 | 2019-07-07 18:30:00   | 2019-07-07 14:30:00 |CATHERIN
```

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Comment: Incidentally, I don't think the title in any way relates to the question.

Comment: Given that the data set is dynamic, in what order should the columns appear?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is at most one row of each type for each person, you can do this using conditional aggregation:

```
select name,
       max(case when action = 'INTIME' then dateandtime end) as intime,
       max(case when action = 'OUTTIME' then dateandtime end) as outtime,
       max(case when action = 'LUNCH' then dateandtime end) as lunch
from t
group by name;
```

If you have multiple values for a given name, I would recommend that you ask a *new* question with details on how to handle that situation.

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response but the action can be totally dynamic these are only 3 scenarios i given in question there are many more like leave, break, meeting ,tea break and so on How one can dynamically handle the same,This is one day scenario if there are records of say Week how this query will work using this

Comment: Using pivot, you can't have a dynamic number of columns, unless you generate dynamic sql and then use sp_executeSQL. But at that point you'd have a variable number of columns, so your downstream report/webpage would have to support it.

Comment: @LALITACHAREKAR . . . Then you need dynamic SQL.  You can look up examples for the database that you are using.

Comment: select name,dob,city
       max(case when action = 'INTIME' then dateandtime end) as intime,
       max(case when action = 'OUTTIME' then dateandtime end) as outtime,
       max(case when action = 'LUNCH' then dateandtime end) as lunch
       from t
       group by name;

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following, which uses application code to handle the pivoting/rearrangement of an array...

```
<?php

/*
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,dt DATETIME NOT NULL
,action VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'John'     ,'2019-07-07 10:00:00','in'),
(2,'John'     ,'2019-07-07 18:00:00','out'),
(3,'William'  ,'2019-07-07 10:02:00','in'),
(4,'Catherine','2019-07-07 10:10:00','in'),
(5,'John'     ,'2019-07-07 13:00:00','lunch'),
(6,'Catherine','2019-07-07 18:30:00','out'),
(7,'Catherine','2019-07-07 14:30:00','lunch'),
(8,'William'  ,'2019-07-07 19:14:00','in');
*/

require('path/to/connnection/stateme.nts');

$query = "
SELECT id
     , name
     , dt
     , action
  FROM my_table
 ORDER
    BY name
     , action;
";

$result = mysqli_query($db,$query);

$array = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$array[] = $row;
}

foreach($array as $v){
$new_array[$v['name']][$v['action']] = $v['dt'];
}


print_r($new_array);

?>
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [Catherine] => Array
        (
            [in] => 2019-07-07 10:10:00
            [lunch] => 2019-07-07 14:30:00
            [out] => 2019-07-07 18:30:00
        )

    [John] => Array
        (
            [in] => 2019-07-07 10:00:00
            [lunch] => 2019-07-07 13:00:00
            [out] => 2019-07-07 18:00:00
        )

    [William] => Array
        (
            [in] => 2019-07-07 19:14:00
        )

)
```

Comment: select name,dob,city
       max(case when action = 'INTIME' then dateandtime end) as intime,
       max(case when action = 'OUTTIME' then dateandtime end) as outtime,
       max(case when action = 'LUNCH' then dateandtime end) as lunch
       from t
       group by name;     there are other columns as well which i applied in this query but it didnt work

Comment: Do you see any aggregation in my query? No. Under these circumstances I fail to grasp the relevance of your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I had used a CTE which is worked for me and is as follows

```
WITH cte 
AS (SELECT Row_number() 
OVER( 
partition BY [name] 
ORDER BY [name]) AS rn, *FROM   table1)           
SELECT a.[dateandtime]  AS [IN], 
b.[dateandtime]  AS [OUT], 
a.[action]  AS [myaction], 
   c.[dateandtime]  AS [lunchTIME] 
FROM   (SELECT * 
FROM   cte a 
WHERE  rn = 1) a 
JOIN (SELECT * 
FROM   cte b 
WHERE  rn = 2) b 
ON a.[name] = b.[name] 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * 
FROM   cte b 
WHERE  rn = 3) c 
ON a.[name] = c.[name]
```