# MYSQL group the columns and rank

Tags: php, mysql

```
I'd.  Regno.  Class.    Subject      Score   
1.     111.      JSS1.    Mth.            60
2.     112.       JSS1.    Mth.           50
3.      111        JSS1.    Eng.          60
4.      112.       JSS1.    Eng.          80 etc
```

Please, how can I use Php and MySQL to use the above records to get the below records dynamically without specifying the subjects?

```
Regno.      Eng.        Math.    Total.    Position
111.        60.         60.         120.       2nd
112.        80.         50.          130.      1st
```

I greet all the programmers in this forum, I posted the below few days ago and I was given the below answer, thanks. But I don't want to specify the subjects (e.g Mth, Eng etc), I want an advance sample code that can do it dynamically? Thanks.

```
select t.*
, rank() over (order by total) as ranking
from    (
select regno
, sum(case when subject = 'Mth.' then score end) as math
, sum(case when subject = 'Eng.' then score end) as eng
, sum(score) as total
from test.scores
group by regno
) t
```

Comment: What about non-programmers?

Comment: check out this [link](https://www.sqlshack.com/multiple-options-to-transposing-rows-into-columns/)

Comment: In the context of PHP, I think the suggested link is a daft idea. This is a simple rearrangement of an array. Here's an example that I think is more appropriate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57359481/get-corrosponding-record-of-row-in-another-column-of-sql-table/57360666#57360666