# how to make query with group and multiple joins

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, where-clause, prestashop-1.6

Hello i need some light about this.
I have 3 tables:

PRODUCTS

| id_product | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | car |
| 2 | plane |
| 3 | bike |

QUANTITY

| id_product | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 17 |
| 3 | 5 |

PRICE

| id_product | id_group | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5.00 |
| 1 | 2 | 6.00 |
| 1 | 3 | 7.00 |
| 2 | 1 | 10.00 |
| 2 | 2 | 11.00 |
| 2 | 3 | 12.00 |
| 3 | 1 | 20.00 |
| 3 | 2 | 21.00 |
| 3 | 3 | 22.00 |

And with the query i hope to get this result:

| name | price1 | price2 | price3 | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| car | 5.00 | 6.00 | 7.00 | 10 |
| plane | 10.00 | 11.00 | 12.00 | 17 |
| bike | 20.00 | 21.00 | 22.00 | 5 |

I cannot goal this result my query is:

```
    SELECT
product.name,price.price,quantity.quantity
FROM product

LEFT JOIN price
ON product.id_product = price.id_product
WHERE price.id_group = 1
LEFT JOIN price
ON product.id_product = price.id_product
WHERE price.id_group = 2
LEFT JOIN price
ON product.id_product = price.id_product
WHERE price.id_group = 3

LEFT JOIN quantity
ON product.id_product = quantity.id_product
```

Comment: What if there are more than 3 id_groups for each product?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Comment: thanks @forpas for the edition :)
well i controll the id_groups and it fixed (there are only 3).

Comment: Also in the table QUANTITY is there only 1 quantity for each product?

Comment: @Strawberry i don't understand what you have said...
this is for my prestashop website and in template code i make a foreach (php)...but for each row is controlled by id_product.

Comment: That's a simple re-arrangement of an array - there are hundreds of examples out there. Here's one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57359481/get-corrosponding-record-of-row-in-another-column-of-sql-table/57360666#57360666

Comment: yes @forpas there is only 1 quantity for each product.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, use conditional aggregation in the table `price` to get the prices and then join:

```
SELECT p.name, t.price1, t.price2, t.price3, q.quantity
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN quantity q ON q.id_product = p.id_product
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT id_product,
         MAX(CASE WHEN id_group = 1 THEN price END) price1,
         MAX(CASE WHEN id_group = 2 THEN price END) price2,
         MAX(CASE WHEN id_group = 3 THEN price END) price3
  FROM price
  GROUP BY id_product
) t ON t.id_product = p.id_product
```

Comment: Thanks Forpas works as expected :)
sorry about the delay ... thanks